# Ignore certain IPs or IP ranges while using Dynamic IP Security setting in IIS web.config

Tags: azure, api, iis, web-config

I have an API running and a front-end node server running for SSR purposes. Everything is on Azure using App Services.

Both the node server and client(s) make requests to the API.

I am trying to apply 'dynamicIpSecurity' in the web.config of my API, but do not want my node server IPs to be throttled by that security setting since it is a trusted 'client'.

Goal is to throttle all other client IPs through this setting in case a client decides to try ddos-ing me or load testing my API without my permission to find loopholes.

I currently have the the dynamic ip security settings commented out, but this is how they look.

```
<dynamicIpSecurity>
    <!--Restricting single IP to make maximum of 20 concurrent request at a time-->
    <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="20" />

    <!--Restricting single IP NOT to make more than 50 requests within 3 seconds duration-->
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="50" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="3000"/>
</dynamicIpSecurity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/), `<dynamicIpSecurity>` could only use `denyByConcurrentRequests` and `denyByRequestRate` to blocking of requests from IP address based on `The number of concurrent requests` or
`The number of requests over a period of time`.

Although as the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions) said, `<dynamicIpSecurity>` could `Allow list of IP addresses that will not be blocked`. However, in web.config it could not configure, you could only do it in IIS.

So, if you still want to defines a list of IP-based security restrictions you could use `<ipSecurity>` like below:

```
<security>
   <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
      <add ipAddress="192.168.100.1" />
      <add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
   </ipSecurity>
   <dynamicIpSecurity enableLoggingOnlyMode="true">
       <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10" />
       <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="30"
           requestIntervalInMilliseconds="300" />
   </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: Doesnt the `allowUnlisted="true"` ignore IPs listed underneath `<ipSecurity>`? I do want to allow any IP to access the API, just certain IPs to be ignored from the `<dynamicIpSecurity>` throttling. I could also just be misunderstanding what `allowUnlisted="true"` actually does...

Comment: If you want to locks down the server, preventing access to all IP address unless they are listed, you could use `allowUnlisted="false"`. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/#configuration).

Comment: If it helps you, please mark it as answer to close the issue:)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. I do not want to lock down the server. I want all IPs to have access to the API. I only want the `<dynamicIpSecurity>` rules to not be used for certain IPs (my node servers).

Comment: The answer was almost right, you need to add allowed="true", i.e. <add ipAddress="192.168.100.1" allowed="true" />

Comment: @RobSedgwick adding `allowed="true"` doesn't work as well.